# SNM (Static Noise Margin) and DNM (Dynamic Noise Margin) confusion in digital circuits

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, signal-to-noise

I've found in several sites that SNM is the [min](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/343484/what-is-snmstatic-noise-margin-in-sram) between [NMH](http://dit.upc.es/lpdntt/biblio/BREUS/HAU93a.pdf) and NML where NMH=VOHmin-VIHmin and NML=VILmax -VOLmax

But [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221295950_Dynamic_Noise_Margin_Definitions_and_Model) really confuses me, because it uses the same graphics and apparently the same definition to DNM.

Can someone explain to me the difference between both concepts?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the second paragraph of the Introduction section. It appears that the paper is trying to consider that a very narrow input pulse is less likely to cause a change in the output voltage than a pulse with higher duration.

Comment: So basically its saying its the same definition but it's time dependent? I don't understand why are neccesary two definitions then. I don't see the changes in VIH,VOL,etc, they change?